# Is it OK to do IO inside java 8 streams?

Tags: java, java8

Example to question in title:

```
List<UUID> ids = dao1.getContactsOfUser(userId);
List<String> contact_names = ids.stream
    .map(uid -> dao2.getContactByUid(uid)) //is it ok? 
    .filter(contact -> contact.getPhone!=null)
    .map(contact -> contact.getFullName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I know that it works, and even works fine, but is there no snags?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it OK to do IO inside java 8 streams?
>   Depends on what you mean by *OK*.

**»OK«** in the sense of *does it work*: *yes* why shouldn't it.

**»OK«** in the sense of *should I*: No!

That is *not encouraged*. It doesn't make sense,retrieving first a user with a call to the database and then retrive contacts with *n* more requests simply because you wanted the name of the contact, when one request will do?

Enhance your query in joining in the contacts' name and build an aggregate column, which contains the information needed.

Comment: Firstly, in is just example.
Secondly - what if there is no JOIN's? I.e. what if it is dao to Cassandra?

Comment: The problem stays the same: minimize the requests. Perhaps this helps: http://www.datastax.com/2015/03/how-to-do-joins-in-apache-cassandra-and-datastax-enterprise or http://spark.apache.org/sql/

Comment: As I understand relationship between Cassandra and Spark your way doesn't minimize requests, only wrap them in one request to Spark, but Spark anyway does exactly same set of requests to Cassandra.